# Get current public IP / host used while connecting via SSH with ansible

Tags: networking, ssh, ansible

I have an ansible `host` file (called `my_host_file`) similar to this:

```
[my_group_name]
MY_PUBLIC_IP_FOR_VM_XYZ
```

Then I am attempting a few different approaches in a YAML playbook (called `my_playbook.yml`) similar to this:

```
---
- hosts: my_group_name
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
  - debug: var=hostvars
  - setup:
    register: allfacts
  - debug: var=allfacts
  - debug: var=ansible_default_ipv4.address
  - debug: var=ansible_hostname
  - command: bash -c "dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"
    register: my_public_ip_as_ansible_var
```

I run everything like this: `ansible-playbook -v -i my_host_file my_playbook.yml`

I would like to get the public IP address in the `my_host_file` file (`MY_PUBLIC_IP_FOR_VM_XYZ`) **at runtime** in a different way than using the `dig` command combined with `opendns` then storing that into the variable `my_public_ip_as_ansible_var`.

After all, this has been used by ansible itself to establish the SSH session, so it may be stored somewhere.

I can not find this information either:

- in the `hostvars` (actually here I can find it here, but I can also see all the other hosts, so I have no way to recognize the current SSH session from the group of hosts)
- in the `allfacts` (using `setup: [...]`) variable (only the IP address in the private network, among many useful info about that VM like disk size, networking, OS kernel version etc.)
- in `ansible_default_ipv4.address` (this is the IP of the private network)
- in `ansible_hostname` (this is the host name, not the public IP I've used in `my_host_file`)

Is there a cleaner way / more ansible-ish way of getting the host used during the SSH session that comes from `my_host_file`?

Comment: This is infrastructure as code that is currently versioned in a git repository just as any other source code. Also in this specific question I am defining variable and assigning values to them. If this question is off topic then the combination of tags that I was allowed to use needs to be managed in a more effective way by who administer this board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get host alias from inventory file you would use `inventory_hostname` variable.

There is also `ansible_host` variable, because inventory alias and actual host may differ.

Comment: Ok got it, putting all these pieces together is not trivial for a first-time user. I also found out that in my `my_host_file` I could have a line like `MY_HOST_AS_LABEL my_public_ip=MY_PUBLIC_IP_FOR_VM_XYZ some_variable=xyz`, then I could retrieve the 2 extra pieces of information with `- debug: var=my_public_ip` and  `- debug: var=some_variable` whereas `MY_HOST_AS_LABEL` (not an IP address) could be retrieved as you mentioned using `- debug: var=inventory_hostname`

Answer (score 7):

- `inventory_hostname` : host name declared in your inventory (can be the IP, the DNS or a logical name)
- `inventory_hostname_short` : the same but with removing everything after the first dot
- `ansible_nodename` : hostname of the host (result of the commande `hostname`)
- `ansible_hostname` : short hostname of the host (result of command `hostname --short`)
- `ansible_fqdn` : full hostname of the host (with domain) (result of command `hostname --fqdn`)
- `ansible_default_ipv4.address` : IPv4 address to access `8.8.8.8` from the host
- `ansible_ethX.ipv4.address` : IPV4 address of ethX interface of the host
- `ansible_ssh_host` : hostname or IP used to access the host with SSH **if defined in the inventory**

Example :

```
# hosts
[mygroup]
  myremote.foo.bar ansible_ssh_host=my-machine.mydomain.com
```

- `inventory_hostname`: myremote.foo.bar
- `inventory_hostname_short`: myremote
- `ansible_nodename`: my-host
- `ansible_hostname`: my-host
- `ansible_fqdn`: my-host.domain.local
- `ansible_default_ipv4.address`: 1.2.3.4
- `ansible_eth1.ipv4.address`: 5.6.7.8
- `ansible_ssh_host`: my-machine.mydomain.com

Comment: Yeah but if my VM is on the internet with a public IP but I did not map it to something that could be resolved by a DNS e.g. `myremote.foo.bar` (or I am not aware of that mapping at the moment), then I need to find a way to use this public IP to identify that VM. So probably using an entry in the `host` file like `MY_PUBLIC_IP_FOR_VM_XYZ some_variable=MY_LOGICAL_NAME` makes me able to retrieve both the IP via `inventory_hostname` and the logical name via `some_variable` (so I can use these aliases e.g. to makeup `/etc/hosts` in a private network)

Comment: `ansible_ssh_host` can be en IP address, so you can set in your inventory `MY_HOST_AS_LABEL ansible_ssh_host=MY_HOST_PUBLIC_IP`, then access `ansible_ssh_host` as the public IP address of your VM. But be sure in that case to always use IP address for `ansible_ssh_host` (if you use DNS entry and then use it as an IP, it will fail)